# Efficiently update AWS elastic beanstalk app with new version

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a python flask web app on elastic beanstalk. My app includes a photo album which takes up a decent amount of space on the server. I'm wondering if it possible to make changes to my website and only upload the changes, in a similar way to github, instead of having to reupload all of the files at once. Currently the only way I know of uploading new files is to choose a folder with all of the files in the web app during the "upload and deploy" step. When I have a large amount of files, this seems like an step for small changes.

The other option I can think of would be to store the photos on s3 and use both services, but I wanted to see if there was another option before refactoring everything.

Comment: How are you currently deploying to elastic beanstalk?  [git is supported](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb3-cli-git.html).  May be worth investigating further to see if this solves your issue...

Comment: you can rsync needed files and restart the app server